# how read() method is executing twice

Tags: java, scjp

But i dont understand why its a? why read() method is executing twice?

```
 import java.io.*;
  public class asrts{
    public static void main(String argv[])throws Exception{
      StringReader sr=new StringReader("Kavp");
      sr.read();
      char c=(char)sr.read();
      System.out.println(c);
    }
  }
```

Output is "a"

please help

Comment: You do call `read` twice.

Comment: result of first call is "K", but you are not using this result; second call gives "a"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

```
  sr.read();                  <--- call #1, returns "K" and loses it
  char c=(char)sr.read();
               ^^^^^^^^^--- call #2, returns "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

> why read() method is executing twice?

Because you called it twice.